# React-Router v6: Can you change the destination of a <Prompt /> component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom, prompt

I have a flow in my app that has the user going through a few pages.

Normal flow would be 1 -> 2 -> 3

I want to restrict the user from going back with a prompt, which is not an issue, but if the user performs an action on page 3, I don't want to allow the user to go back to page 2. Is there a way I can change the back button destination to page 1 when the user sees a prompt on page 3?

My first idea was creating a `useEffect` that would check if they should go to page 1 instead of page 2, and modify the history stack, then clean it up in the return function of the useEffect. I can't figure out how to accomplish this right now since react-router v6 removed useHistory. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe with `useBlocker`?

Thanks!